# Firefox freeze while working with selenium

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

i'm currently working on an automation project that use selenium on Firefox
my test works find as long that i'm not focus on the Firefox windows
once i focus on the Firefox window its immediately freeze without recovery
i disabled all security options and i have no more ideas what to do 
so the question is how can i prevent firefox from freezing on me
(i'm working with Firefox version 3.6.28)

Comment: Please, show us the code (and possibly a minimal testcase to run it on) that freezes the browser. Is the Firefox frozen in a way "Not responding to anything", or just the Selenium script blocks somewhere (where?) for indefinite time?

Comment: ok sorry for being unclear the question is how to prevent the freezing when i focus on firefox windows

Comment: this happens with every selenium related test i have and i don't focus on Firedox the test completing just fine, Firefox frozen like in your first description not responding to anything and faded

Comment: If your test works fine without focusing, why are you aiming to focus on it? Your problem could purely be that you are focusing incorrectly (or do not need to at all?). Providing some code as Slanec will allow for better answers.

Comment: I have the same problem, Firefox just freezes (*this program is not responding*). The code to reproduce the problem is this: `new FireFoxDriver()`